# Theres and way to compare column names and if they match, change the name to the one thats in the first Database

Tags: r, data-science

I was curious of how can I do a kind of function that remplace the name of columna based on matches.

For example, lets say that I have a `df1` that contain the followings colnames

```
colnames(df1)
 [1] "IES PADRE"                               "Institución de Educación Superior (IES)"
 [3] "Sector IES"                              "Carácter IES"                           
 [5] "Departamento de \ndomicilio de la IES"   "Municipio de\ndomicilio de la IES"      
 [7] "Programa Académico"                      "Nivel de Formación"                     
 [9] "Nivel de Formación"                      "Metodología"                            
[11] "Área de Conocimiento"                    "Núcleo Básico del Conocimiento (NBC)"   
[13] "Departamento de oferta del programa"     "Municipio de oferta del programa"       
[15] "Género"                                  "Año"                                    
[17] "Semestre"                                "Matriculados"
```

And a `df2` that contains these:

```
 colnames(a21)
 [1] "CÓDIGO DE LA INSTITUCIÓN"                "IES_PADRE"                              
 [3] "INSTITUCIÓN DE EDUCACIÓN SUPERIOR (IES)" "PRINCIPAL O SECCIONAL"                  
 [5] "SECTOR IES"                              "IES ACREDITADA"                         
 [7] "CARACTER IES"                            "CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (IES)"          
 [9] "DEPARTAMENTO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES"     "CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (IES)"             
[11] "MUNICIPIO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES"        "CÓDIGO SNIES DEL PROGRAMA"              
[13] "PROGRAMA ACADÉMICO"                      "PROGRAMA ACREDITADO"                    
[15] "NIVEL ACADÉMICO"                         "NIVEL DE FORMACIÓN"                     
[17] "METODOLOGÍA"                             "ÁREA DE CONOCIMIENTO"                   
[19] "NÚCLEO BÁSICO DEL CONOCIMIENTO (NBC)"    "DESC CINE CAMPO AMPLIO"                 
[21] "DESC CINE CAMPO ESPECIFICO"              "DESC CINE CODIGO DETALLADO"             
[23] "CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (PROGRAMA)"      "DEPARTAMENTO DE OFERTA DEL PROGRAMA"    
[25] "CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (PROGRAMA)"         "MUNICIPIO DE OFERTA DEL PROGRAMA"       
[27] "SEXO"                                    "AÑO"                                    
[29] "SEMESTRE"                                "MATRICULADOS"
```

As you can see, theres some titles that have the same name but in uppercase, others thant change in typing a Little and others that simply not match.

I want to keep those that are similar and change it to coincide with the typing on df1, its possible to deal with that?

Comment: Define "similar". A good start would make to make everything lowercase, for example using `tolower()`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to define "similar":

- different in case only
- presence of accents (otherwise identical, with or without case)
- string distance (`stringdist` package)

The third is incredibly risky, as it can mis-classify fairly easily. See for instance,

```r
stringdist::stringdist("SEXO", "Año")
# [1] 4
```

This is a very close "distance", but clearly the words are not the same. You are free to play with that (and `stringdist::stringdistmatrix(names1, names21)`) to find likely candidates, but I feel it'll have too high a false-positive rate for my likes.

I'll use the other two:

```r
ind21 <- match(tolower(stringi::stri_trans_general(names21, id = "Latin-ASCII")), tolower(stringi::stri_trans_general(names1, id = "Latin-ASCII")))
ind21
#  [1] NA NA  2 NA  3 NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA  7 NA NA  8 10 11 12 NA NA NA NA 13 NA 14 NA 16 17 18
names21[!is.na(ind21)] <- names1[na.omit(ind21)]
```

For easy comparison, here are the original and modified versions of `names21`:

```
                                  original                                     new
1                 CÓDIGO DE LA INSTITUCIÓN                CÓDIGO DE LA INSTITUCIÓN
2                                IES_PADRE                               IES_PADRE
3  INSTITUCIÓN DE EDUCACIÓN SUPERIOR (IES) Institución de Educación Superior (IES)
4                    PRINCIPAL O SECCIONAL                   PRINCIPAL O SECCIONAL
5                               SECTOR IES                              Sector IES
6                           IES ACREDITADA                          IES ACREDITADA
7                             CARACTER IES                            Carácter IES
8            CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (IES)           CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (IES)
9      DEPARTAMENTO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES     DEPARTAMENTO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES
10              CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (IES)              CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (IES)
11        MUNICIPIO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES        MUNICIPIO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES
12               CÓDIGO SNIES DEL PROGRAMA               CÓDIGO SNIES DEL PROGRAMA
13                      PROGRAMA ACADÉMICO                      Programa Académico
14                     PROGRAMA ACREDITADO                     PROGRAMA ACREDITADO
15                         NIVEL ACADÉMICO                         NIVEL ACADÉMICO
16                      NIVEL DE FORMACIÓN                      Nivel de Formación
17                             METODOLOGÍA                             Metodología
18                    ÁREA DE CONOCIMIENTO                    Área de Conocimiento
19    NÚCLEO BÁSICO DEL CONOCIMIENTO (NBC)    Núcleo Básico del Conocimiento (NBC)
20                  DESC CINE CAMPO AMPLIO                  DESC CINE CAMPO AMPLIO
21              DESC CINE CAMPO ESPECIFICO              DESC CINE CAMPO ESPECIFICO
22              DESC CINE CODIGO DETALLADO              DESC CINE CODIGO DETALLADO
23      CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (PROGRAMA)      CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (PROGRAMA)
24     DEPARTAMENTO DE OFERTA DEL PROGRAMA     Departamento de oferta del programa
25         CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (PROGRAMA)         CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (PROGRAMA)
26        MUNICIPIO DE OFERTA DEL PROGRAMA        Municipio de oferta del programa
27                                    SEXO                                    SEXO
28                                     AÑO                                     Año
29                                SEMESTRE                                Semestre
30                            MATRICULADOS                            Matriculados
```

---

Starting data:

```r
names1 <- c("IES PADRE", "Institución de Educación Superior (IES)", "Sector IES", "Carácter IES", "Departamento de \ndomicilio de la IES", "Municipio de\ndomicilio de la IES", "Programa Académico", "Nivel de Formación", "Nivel de Formación", "Metodología", "Área de Conocimiento", "Núcleo Básico del Conocimiento (NBC)", "Departamento de oferta del programa", "Municipio de oferta del programa", "Género", "Año", "Semestre", "Matriculados")
names21 <- c("CÓDIGO DE LA INSTITUCIÓN", "IES_PADRE", "INSTITUCIÓN DE EDUCACIÓN SUPERIOR (IES)", "PRINCIPAL O SECCIONAL", "SECTOR IES", "IES ACREDITADA", "CARACTER IES", "CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (IES)", "DEPARTAMENTO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES", "CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (IES)", "MUNICIPIO DE DOMICILIO DE LA IES", "CÓDIGO SNIES DEL PROGRAMA", "PROGRAMA ACADÉMICO", "PROGRAMA ACREDITADO", "NIVEL ACADÉMICO", "NIVEL DE FORMACIÓN", "METODOLOGÍA", "ÁREA DE CONOCIMIENTO", "NÚCLEO BÁSICO DEL CONOCIMIENTO (NBC)", "DESC CINE CAMPO AMPLIO",  "DESC CINE CAMPO ESPECIFICO", "DESC CINE CODIGO DETALLADO", "CÓDIGO DEL DEPARTAMENTO (PROGRAMA)", "DEPARTAMENTO DE OFERTA DEL PROGRAMA", "CÓDIGO DEL MUNICIPIO (PROGRAMA)", "MUNICIPIO DE OFERTA DEL PROGRAMA", "SEXO", "AÑO", "SEMESTRE", "MATRICULADOS")
```